# Deleting disk partion with ubuntu on it

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'd like to delete everything from this pc's HDD. It has Ubuntu on it, so I can't reformat it. I got a Live CD with Ubuntu 12.04 on it from a library.

I went to BIOS and set DVD-ROM as the first boot device, saved and rebooted. It still boots into Ubuntu 16.04 that is on my HDD, so I can't delete the partion.

The CD shows up in the Home Folder with the name "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386" it has all the files in it, so the CDROM is fine. What should I do? I do not have multiple partitions. My problem is the PC won't boot using the CDROM, so I can't delete the partion with ubuntu 16.04 on it. I am planning on installing Steam OS so I'd like the drive to be clean.

Comment: It sounds like the DVD Disc wasn't formatted properly. Did you use startup disc creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but regardless of whether you want to end up with linux or windows or something else, you typically want to run the installer for the operating system of choice and select to "replace the entire drive" with the new operating system.  This will normally re-partition and format everything so you start from scratch, it's not technical at all.  If you want to end up with linux, then run the linux install from media (DVD or USB or etc) and select the option like that.  For windows, same story.

If you are attempting to add your drive as a separate drive under an existing operating system, it may be set to be the primary boot device so you end up booting into it.  You said you already tried to boot from DVD media, but as another person already said, if the media is bad it would move on to the next option.  You can probably press F8 or F12 or something like that from your POST screen to select your preferred boot device, you will need to read your BIOS documentation or look closely at the POST screen when your computer first starts to display content after a restart.  POST is the computer's very first screen (Power On Self Test) if you didn't know.  You can normally press DEL or F2 to get into BIOS and some other key like F8 or F12 often to get into a boot selection menu.  I think not all BIOS systems support that though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove Ubuntu no matter the future purpose of the hard drive:

- If you want to use it as data storage you can repartition and reformat it to your liking with the computer and operating system that's connected to it.
- If you want to install a different operating system the installer of that operating system will (or at least should) allow you to repartition and reformat the drive. See for instance [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](/q/133533/175814).